# SVN checkout error Malformed XML: no element found

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am trying to checkout from svn, the URL and credentials are correct. I am able to access using the portal and also I have done checkout previously without any issue.

but currently I'm not able to checkout from svn. Can anyone advice how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, make sure that the URL to the repository is correct. Most likely, you get the error because the URL is incorrect.

Ask your colleagues or an admin for the correct repository URL. If you use VisualSVN Server to host the repositories, see the article for instructions how to find the correct URL to be used with SVN clients:

- [**KB102: Subversion client errors caused by inappropriate repository URL**](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00102/)